# ts(2322) Typescript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, class-transformer

I'm maybe missing something but I try to use `ClassConstructor` from `class-transformer` and I have an issue

```
import { ClassConstructor } from 'class-transformer'

class A {}

type Types = A

const myFunction = <T extends Types>(type: ClassConstructor<T>): T[] => {
  if (type === A) {
    const arrayOfA: A[] = []

    return arrayOfA
  }
  return []
}
```

After doing this, for the `return arrayOfA`, typescript tell me:

```
Type 'A[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'A' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'.ts(2322)
```

This is the function of `class-transformer`

```
export declare type ClassConstructor<T> = {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
};
```

Does someone have an idea to replace `ClassConstructor` or to resolve this `different subtype of constraint` error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that T will typically be determined by the type of the `type` argument Consider the following:

```
import { ClassConstructor } from 'class-transformer'

class A { a = 1; b = "" }
class B { a = ""; b = 1 }
class C {}

type Types = A | B

const myFunction = <T extends Types>(type: ClassConstructor<T>): T[] => {
  return []
}

myFunction(A) // returns A[]
myFunction(B) // returns B[]
myFunction(C) // doesn't compile
```

So what is happening to you is that typescript is not picking up on the meaning of this conditional: `if (type === A)`. Assume that `Types` were defined in your code like in mine above. Since it doesn't understand the meaning of the conditional it is as if you were doing:

```
type Types = A | B

const myFunction = <T extends Types>(type: ClassConstructor<T>): T[] => {    
  const arrayOfA: A[] = []

  return arrayOfA
}
```

And since T could just as easily be B as A, and A and B are not compatible it understandibly complains.

The solution is simple, just change the type of `arrayOfA` to `T[]`:

```
const myFunction = <T extends Types>(type: ClassConstructor<T>): T[] => {
  if (type === A) {
    const arrayOfA: T[] = []

    return arrayOfA
  }
  return []
}
```

When you hover over a function call like this:

```
myFunction(A)
```

You will see that it has correctly picked up a return type of `A[]`

Alternatively, if you are operating on arrayOfA and need to have it typed as `A[]` you can coerce it to a `T[]` before returning it:

```
const myFunction = <T extends Types>(type: ClassConstructor<T>): T[] => {
  if (type === A) {
    const arrayOfA: A[] = []
    doSomethingWithAValues(arrayOfA);

    return arrayOfA as T[]
  }
  return []
}
```